# .WeldService: com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayInd exOutOfBoundsException: 3"}}}} when using selenium with jboss

Tags: java, selenium, jboss, selenium-webdriver

I have developed a project. Now for testing I am using selenium. When selenium-server-standlone.jar is added or selenium-java.jar(with other lib provided by selenium) is added then it gives this exception:

.WeldService: com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3"}}}}

The relevant code is:

```
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://localhost:8081";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```

The Selenium version is 2.42.2 and JBoss version is 7.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that, Selenium Client package contains guava 15.0 which is giving this exception when using with JBoss. If I use guava 17.0 then there is no exeption.